# Display at specific point

Tags: image, matlab, pixel

I try to display an image(IM2) of size `Tc * Tr` pixel with a very precise coordinate point (The top left corner is at the coordinate point `(r, c)`. For this I use the following function `image([r  r+Tr], [c Tc-c], IM2)`. Unfortunately the obtained image doesn't meet my expectations.

Does anyone have an idea how to implement the function or another function to use?

Comment: A couple of observations: First, the coordinate order should be `x,y` (i.e., `c,r`). Second, why are you subtracting `c` from `Tc`? If `c` is greater than the height of the image, that wouldn't display anything. It's hard for us to know what your expected image looks like. Could you explain a bit more, or post your current output and tell us what's wrong with it?

Comment: Your example image is doing more than simply moving the origin. Please update your question with what you are actually trying to do using [edit].

Answer (score 0):

[image]

My expectation is to have an image like this with the top left corner at the coordinate (c,r). As I say my main problem is the implementation of function image. "image([r  r+Tr], [c Tc-c], IM2)" is just what I tried but the result was caotic.

Comment: Please add this to the original question using `edit` rather than posting it as an Answer.